# How do I setup dynamic VLAN assignment on an autonomous Cisco 1142n?

Tags: ios, radius, access-point, dynamic-vlan-assignment

I've gotten my Cisco 1142n autonomous AP configured with every option under the sun, but I still can't get dynamic VLAN assignment working!

I verified the following:

- I give priority to VLAN assignment via RADIUS with `aaa authorization network default group radius`
- The encryption across all VLANs which might be assigned is the same
- Using `debug radius auth` I can tell that the AP is receiving the appropriate RADIUS attributes
- I've ensured that the necessary broadcast messages are being sent (on capability and membership changes)

Long story short, I'm pulling my hair out like you CANNOT believe. What am I missing?

Here's my running config: http://dpaste.com/hold/621393/

Thank you SO much in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2171534 it's impossible without an WLC.
I came to this conclusion after trying the same thing for hours.